# When does a System.Timers Timer get disposed?

Tags: c#, dispose, system.timers.timer

As stated in the title,
When is a `System.Timers` Timer disposed?

In a scenario where I would run a console application and simply use the following code

```
var timer = new Timer( interval );
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += MainTimer_Elapsed;
```

Will the timer be disposed at some point or will it be "alive" forever?
Note: With "forever" I mean until the application is closed.

Comment: You can visit this link for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955821/system-timers-timer-lifecycle

Comment: It will be alive "forever" because you don't unsubscribe the event handler or dispose the timer. It implements `IDisposable` for one reason: it uses unmanaged resources, in this case a Win32 timer which events prevents the timer from being garbage collected.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - unlike threads, timers don't keep themselves rooted. So, at some unknown future point in time, the timer will be GCed and at that point it will probably dispose itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: haven't tested it but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962172/why-does-a-system-timers-timer-survive-gc-but-not-system-threading-timer) suggests that `System.Timers.Timer` might not be garbage collected(depends on the constructor used).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Tim is right, System.Timers.Timer will not be collected if you don't unsubsribe or dispose.